# Best way to merge two Datatables

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I need to marge two datatables with condition. I have a datatable where the data comes from a local XML Database and another datatable where the data comes from a remote SQL Server.

If any update made in the remote datatable I need to update/merge with the local datatable. Here is what I have so far:

```
Public Sub MargeTwoTable()

    Dim SQL As String = ""
    Dim RemoteTable As New DataTable
    Dim LocalTable As DataTable
    Dim dal As New DalComon
    Dim yy As Integer = 0
    Dim UpdateDate As String
    Dim TableName As String = "V_Book_Price"


    LocalTable = LoadDataTable(TableName, True)
    UpdateDate = LocalTable.Compute("MAX(update_date)", Nothing)


    SQL = "select * from V_Book_Price where Update_Date > '" & UpdateDate & "'"
    RemoteTable = dal.GetDataSetBySQL(SQL).Tables(0)

    If RemoteTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then

        For i = 0 To RemoteTable.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim st As DataRow


            Dim mm() As DataRow = LocalTable.Select("ID = '" & RemoteTable.Rows(i).Item("ID") & "'")

            If mm.Length = 0 Then

                st = LocalTable.NewRow

                For yy = 0 To RemoteTable.Columns.Count - 1
                    st(yy) = RemoteTable.Rows(i)(yy)
                Next

                LocalTable.Rows.Add(st)

            Else
                st = mm(0)

                For yy = 0 To RemoteTable.Columns.Count - 1
                    If IsDate(RemoteTable.Rows(i)(yy)) Then
                        st(yy) = CDate(RemoteTable.Rows(i)(yy)).ToString("s")
                    Else
                        st(yy) = RemoteTable.Rows(i)(yy)
                    End If
                Next

                mm = Nothing
            End If
        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

In this code data comes from the remote database which updates a date getter then the local database . Both tables have "ID" as the primary key. The code is working well, but the problem is that when more than 1000 records are updated this function takes too long using loops.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not sure if can be applicable, but have you ever looked at the
[DataTable.LoadDataRow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.loaddatarow.aspx) method?.
It seems a good candidate to substitute all of you code above.

Your code could be simplified to these lines

```
Dim row as DataRow
For Each row in RemoteTable.Rows
    LocalTable.LoadDataRow(row.ItemArray, false)
Next
```

Another alternative  could be the [DataTable.Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge.aspx) that could cut your code to a single line

```
LocalTable.Merge(RemoteTable, False)
```

However, the real effectiveness of these two methods depends on the schema compatibility and from the presence of AutoNumber (identity) columns.