# How to LEFT JOIN two Datatable Objects?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq

As the title says I have, at several points in code, two Datatable Objects. I am looking for a convenient solution to join them up, so they can be used as a Datasource. For work-specific reasons i cannot perform those joins on Database-level, as they stem from completely different Databases (each table is already a result of dozens of joins from their respective Database).

All i care about is the mentioned Datasource part, the tables need not necessarily be combined into one actual instance of type Datatable, i just need something that provides an appropiate view.

What i know works, but is impractical due to scale of the application (i have to do this hundreds of times on non-identical tableschemes) is to manually act on DataRow-level. However i cannot imagine being the first person with that problem, so there gotta be a solution that is agnostic of table specific columns (except the respective foreign keys obviously).

In my own testing there are 2 major routes i explored, the first being adding the tables to a DataSet Object and filling the Relations Property with the correct DataRelation Objects. This doesnt work however, because when binding a DataSet you are forced to choose one table from the set and it does not automatically perform the desired join (so why does this even exist?).
The second being LINQ-based. This works if i add a SELECT statement with every column explicitely after a GROUP JOIN, however thats, as mentioned, not what im looking for.

I feel like either of these approaches could work and im simply missing something glaring me into the eye, but i cannot quite figure it out.

I happen to be using VB primarily, but answers in C# are just as good.

Comment: Found this link, which may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671746/best-way-to-merge-two-datatables